# INSERT INTO works in phpMyAdmin but not in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

I'm trying to run a query in php as follows:

```
<?php
        $email = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['email']);
        if(isset($_POST['savedata'])){
            $sql = "INSERT INTO registered (email)
                    VALUES (
                        '$email'
                    )";
            $result = mysql_query($sql);

            if(!$result){
                echo 'something went wrong, please try again.';
                echo mysql_error();
            } else {
                echo '<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="2; url = subscribed.php" />';
            }
        }
    ?>
```

The trigger for execution is coming from the following form:

```
<form action="" method="post">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="sr-only" for="exampleInputEmail2">Email address</label>
        <input type="email" name="email" id="email" class="form-control transparent" placeholder="Your email here...">
    </div>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-warning btn-fill">Notify Me</input>
    <input type="hidden" name="savedata" value="savedata"/>
</form>
```

This works well in phpMyAdmin (of course I change the $email to a real address) but nothing happens in php besides refresh. the DB is not updated and I checked the connection - it's working.
Please advise.
Thanks!

Comment: I suggest you read MySQL injection issues, search on StackOverflow about it as you otherwise will be in danger with your app/site.

Comment: [Don't use mysql_* extension](http://www.php.net/en/mysql_query) as it is deprecated. Use [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) instead.

Comment: I would add you might also look for XSS if this email is coming from unsanitized input field

Comment: If it works well in PHPMyAdmin when providing a real address, what does it say about your generated SQL ? Check the content of your $email variable, or of your $sql variable once generated.

Comment: Hi Guys, thank you so much for your inputs. Important to mention I'm not a developer. Only a guy with some very basic knowledge in php. I understand the risks and this is a landing page form to check interest. I'll appreciate if someone can provide a fixed code as I'm a bit lost.. Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

Try the following query:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO registered (email)
                    VALUES (
                        '".$email."'
                    )";
```

Comment: Why should this change anything ? Variables in double-quoted strings are evaluated the same way as this is.

Comment: This is also bad practice for setting up your SQL as this can introduce SQL Injection.

Comment: Hi Guys, thank you so much for your inputs. Important to mention I'm not a developer. Only a guy with some very basic knowledge in php. I understand the risks and this is a landing page form to check interest. I'll appreciate if someone can provide a fixed code as I'm a bit lost.. Thanks!!